# Clicking a button does something similar to "forward" in table

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

I have code in a content script that traverses a table finding a certain cell and then wraps a button around that cell. I then created a jQuery click command:

```
$(this).click(function(){
    for (var i = 0 ; i <result.length; i++) {
         window.open(result[i].url)
    };
});
```

Which will open a URL on click. Now, when I click the button in the table the Url/urls will open in a new tab, but, will also change the current frame to this:

```
Not Found

The requested URL /BAN2P/bwskfreg.P_AltPin1 was not found.
```

Which is also what happens when right clicking the webpage and clicking "forward".

Does anyone know what is going on? I honestly have no clue what to do to fix this. I can provide more information if I it's necessary.

Comment: Did you add that button to the page, or was it already there? If it was already there, what happens if you click it with your extension disabled?

Comment: I added the button to the page, the buttons functionality is there: it opens the correct url in a separate webpage, yet it changes the frame.

Comment: @rsanchez  added the button to the page, the buttons functionality is there: it opens the correct url in a separate webpage, yet it changes the frame

Answer (score 0):

This is probably because you are not appending the rest of the url.

[**Check this demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/saumil_sss/91ox0f4L/)

You are trying to open `/BAN2P/bwskfreg.P_AltPin1` which is not valid url because it is missing the domain name.

Try something like `http://www.yourdomainname.com/BAN2P/bwskfreg.P_AltPin1`

Comment: No, the button correctly opens the url I specify in a separate tab. This is a result of the webpage that my content script runs on. How can I stop it?

Comment: no, the button correctly opens the url I specify in a separate tab. This is a result of the webpage that my content script runs on. How can I stop it?